# HTML onclick event not loading JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I'm having issues with my **onclick** function that I wasn't having before.  When I originally implemented it on the page, it was working perfectly. Then, once I changed the location of the JS file to a subfolder in the directory, (and changed the location in my HTML) the **onclick** link I made stopped calling the JS function.

```
function namePrompt() {
    var x=prompt("Enter your first and last name:");
    if (x) {
      window.location.href = "http://database.gchandel.com/app_edit.php?name="+x;
    }
}
```

Above is the JS code I'm using, and below is the line that calls the function.

```
<a onclick="namePrompt()">click this link to view your entry.</a>
```

I've tried everything from moving the file back to its original location, to refreshing the page many times, to changing things like function name and file name and none of this has given me any luck.

Also, here's the link to the site I'm working on: [database.gchandel.com](http://database.gchandel.com)

Comment: Check the console, what errors do you see?

Comment: Where is the line in your html that calls to the new js file? Can you write your folfers structure?

Comment: You have not completely commented out your old `validate_form()` function. The closing brace must be commented before your code will execute.

Comment: @HarveyA.Ramer, thank you! I didn't originally have all of that function commented out, then recently commented it. I'm guessing I had some errors in that commented code, resulting in my JS not running, but never the less, it's working now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in your **prompt** syntax, check it [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_prompt.asp)
Syntax of prompt is

```
prompt("", "");
```

While working one is [here](http://jsbin.com/usikikUd/3/edit)